# freeing a double pointer to a linked list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

I  am kind of new to c and tried to use a single linked list for stack implementation. To implement push() and pop() functions I passed a double pointer. In main I initialize Node *node_head to NULL

I use malloc() and free() to successfully handle memory leaks but it seems that I have memory leaks somewhere that I can't figure out. Should I take a different approach when freeing a double pointer? Thank you and here are the two functions:

```
void stack_push(Node **node_head, int d)
{
    Node *node_new = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    node_new -> data = d;
    node_new -> next = *node_head;
    *node_head = node_new;
}

int stack_pop(Node **node_head)
{
    Node *node_togo = *node_head;
    int d = 0;

    if(node_head)
    {
        d = node_togo -> data;
        *node_head = node_togo -> next;
        free(node_togo);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C code. What are these `**` after the function definitions supposed to be? Also, please decide about which of C and C++ you want, they aren't the same language.

Comment: `if(node_head)` should be `if(node_togo)`. This code looks OK, you are probably leaking the memory at the end of program by not freeing the list.

Comment: @MohitJain It would be more readable, yes. But `node_head` and `node_togo` are the same due to assignment.

Comment: @harper It is not for the readability but for correct logic. `node_head` and `node_togo` are not same, `*node_head` and `node_togo` are. As you already dereferenced `node_head` above, it is guaranteed to be non-null and if condition will always be true.

Comment: Mohit is right. However, an attempt to free a NULL pointer would lead to a crash, not to a memory leak, right? This code does not appear to leak, but it may crash/hang when *node_head is NULL, as node_head will never be NULL.

Comment: @ThunderGr Freeing a null pointer has no effect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nice. Then the program would crash on d = node_togo -> data ;)

Comment: @ThunderGr Yes it will crash if you will not check whether *node_head is equal to NULL.

Comment: @ThunderGr Passing a null pointer to free() is perfect, since no action occurs. See section 7.20.3.2 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! I understood the idea of checking *node_head to NULL. On the readability of my code, I think I do not understand where the criticism is coming from. What can I do better to make my code more readable in "C"? Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The only error in your code is in function stack_pop.

```
if(node_head)
```

Of course you may check whether node_head is equal to NULL though in my opinion it is a superflouos check. But you have to check that `*node_head` is not equal to NULL.

The function could look like

```
int stack_pop(Node **node_head)
{
    int d = 0;

    if( *node_head )
    {
        Node *node_togo = *node_head;

        d = node_togo -> data;

        *node_head = node_togo -> next;

        free( node_togo );

    }

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! I understood the idea of checking *node_head to NULL. On the readability of my code, I think I do not understand where the criticism is coming from. What can I do better to make my code more readable in "C"? Thank you again for your help!